# How can we filter facebook ad using graph api explorer on the basis of date_stop

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

I want all the campaigns whose 'date_stop greater than today'for creating the insights.I am posting the request

```
{
  "async": true,
  "data_columns": "['spend','frequency','placement','reach','social_reach','ctr']",
  "default_summary": true,
  "filtering": "[{'field':'date_stop','operator':'GREATER_THAN','value':'2016-03-21 02:03:00'}]",
  "level": "campaign"
}
```

but it always return failed report is there any way to accomplish my requirement using graph api explorer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a parameter time_range ={"since":date,"until":date} if we post this we get the required campaigns